# Module variable documentation error

Tags: python-sphinx

I get the following error while documenting a module variable json_class_index (See [source](https://github.com/sanskrit-coders/sanskrit_data/blob/779ee54f78ef564f42c861064c93108ea0250301/sanskrit_data/schema/common.py#L28)), which does not have a docstring.

The generated documentation [seems to be fine](https://github.com/sanskrit-coders/sanskrit_data/commit/779ee54f78ef564f42c861064c93108ea0250301#diff-b6f7054cc1617a697b4f071e6e0e447c). What is a good fix?

```
reading sources... [100%] sanskrit_data_schema_common                                                                                                                                               
/home/vvasuki/sanskrit_data/sanskrit_data/schema/common.py:docstring of sanskrit_data.schema.common.json_class_index:3: WARNING: Unexpected indentation.
/home/vvasuki/sanskrit_data/sanskrit_data/schema/common.py:docstring of sanskrit_data.schema.common.json_class_index:4: WARNING: Block quote ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.
/home/vvasuki/sanskrit_data/sanskrit_data/schema/common.py:docstring of sanskrit_data.schema.common.json_class_index:7: WARNING: Unexpected indentation.
/home/vvasuki/sanskrit_data/sanskrit_data/schema/common.py:docstring of sanskrit_data.schema.common.json_class_index:8: WARNING: Inline strong start-string without end-string.
```

Edit:
PS: Note that removing the below docstring makes the error disappear, so it seems to be the thing to fix.

```
.. autodata:: json_class_index
  :annotation: Maps jsonClass values to Python object names. Useful for (de)serialization. Updated using update_json_class_index() calls at the end of each module file (such as this one) whose classes may be serialized.
```

Comment: You should put your source code in the question and not provide just a link because linked items can change.

Comment: I wanted to minimize distractions in the question; plus I link to a specific immutable snapshot of the code that cannot be modified (as long as the repository exists in the internet)...

Comment: You reinforced my point. If the repo vanishes, so does the code. It is almost always better to provide the code in your question so that you don't make more work for answerers. Also the link has an anchor that is irrelevant to the error messages, which is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to add a docstring for the variable as follows:

```
#: Maps jsonClass values to Python object names. Useful for (de)serialization. Updated using update_json_class_index() calls at the end of each module file (such as this one) whose classes may be serialized.
json_class_index = {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning messages indicate that the reStructuredText syntax of your docstrings is not valid and needs to be corrected.

Additionally your source code does not comply with PEP 8. [Indentation should be 4 spaces](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation), but your code uses 2, which might cause problems with Sphinx.

First make your code compliant with PEP 8 indentation.

Second, you must have two lines separating whatever precedes info field lists and the info field lists themselves.

Third, if the warnings persist, then look at the line numbers in the warnings—3, 4, 7, and 8—and the warnings themselves. It appears that the warnings correspond to [this block of code](https://github.com/sanskrit-coders/sanskrit_data/blob/779ee54f78ef564f42c861064c93108ea0250301/sanskrit_data/schema/common.py#L81-L94):

```
  @classmethod
  def make_from_dict(cls, input_dict):
    """Defines *our* canonical way of constructing a JSON object from a dict.

    All other deserialization methods should use this.
    Note that this assumes that json_class_index is populated properly!
      - ``from sanskrit_data.schema import *`` before using this should take care of it.
    :param input_dict:
    :return: A subclass of JsonObject
    """
```

Try this instead, post-PEP-8-ification, which should correct most of the warnings caused by faulty white space in your docstring:

```
@classmethod
def make_from_dict(cls, input_dict):
    """
    Defines *our* canonical way of constructing a JSON object from a dict.

    All other deserialization methods should use this.

    Note that this assumes that json_class_index is populated properly!

    - ``from sanskrit_data.schema import *`` before using this should take care of it.

    :param input_dict:
    :return: A subclass of JsonObject
    """
```

This style is acceptable according to [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#multi-line-docstrings). The indentation is visually and vertically consistent, where the triple quotes vertically align with the left indentation. I think it's easier to read.

Comment: @steve-percy Thanks for taking a look. The error messages indicate and I confirm by experimentation (see edit to question) that the error has nothing to do with my indentation choice or docstring for the make_from_dict method..

Comment: @vishvas-vasuki I agree that putting autodoc directives like `autodata` into your Python modules will lead to trouble. However, removal of that docstring does not address the underlying issue. As soon as you try to put the `autodata` directive, or autodoc the method `make_from_dict`, in a reStructuredText source file, you should see the same warnings as before.

Comment: you're wrong there. I am [already autodoc-ing all methods and classes in the file](https://github.com/sanskrit-coders/sanskrit_data/commit/779ee54f78ef564f42c861064c93108ea0250301#diff-b6f7054cc1617a697b4f071e6e0e447c) without any warning, and the result is fine - http://imgur.com/a/McNWn . In other words, you're wrong about the make_from_dict connection.

Comment: That's your docstring rendered as HTML, not autodoc'ing. Anyway, I see you reformatted your docstring close enough to what I suggested, which would have eliminated the warnings.

Comment: That was the result of autodoc-ing done [here](https://github.com/sanskrit-coders/sanskrit_data/blob/master/docs/sanskrit_data_schema_common.rst) . And reformatting this unrelated docstring has zero effect on the warnings :-( .